# Indicate multiple tables in an SQL columns

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am on a project currently and I would like to do several category divided into 5 different table.

Here is the name of the 5 table / category:

- stiga_couper
- stiga_entretenir-nettoyer
- stiga_tailler
- stiga_tondre
- stiga_travailler-terre

Each table contains articles that are associated with that category.

Then I have a general table that is used to group all the references it is called 'stiga' and I wish I could from this table have as a foreign key so that I can read on my site in PHP the data of the desired article

In 'stiga' table i have columns
type and reference

and in the other tables I
type (which is the same as in the 'stiga' table), reference (which is the same as in the 'stiga' table), title is the details of the articles in question

I'm trying to find a solution to restart because there are more than 150 articles and in a table that causes me more than 200 columns and SQL blocks me because I reach the table storage limit

Comment: You should probably rethink your design.  You would probably have one table with all articles as individual rows, each row having the category(foreign key) and a unique article ID, title etc.

Comment: Yes, I do not know how to do it I start in the SQL ..
Creating a table with all the articles is not a problem but SQL blocks me by the number of column, when I reach 199 columns it blocks me because I reach the limit and advise me to use BLOBs but its not do not solve my problems :(

Comment: Why are you creating over 200 columns - what are they for?

Comment: I insert all the details and characteristics of each articles so with 5 different category and 150 articles I arrive at total of 225 columns but it blocks me at 199 ...
So that's why I would like to make a separate category system more readable and no longer have any error

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include examples of your data and your proposed database design.